# maven sign jar and dependencies and then assemly

Tags: java, maven, jar, dependencies, sign

I managed to sign "my jar" and then produce a package of it with the assembly plugin.

I am wondering if there is any way to sign all the dependencies that I want to include on the package?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [onejar-maven-plugin](http://code.google.com/p/onejar-maven-plugin/) to produce  a jar and then sign it

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to take a deep look into [maven-jarsigner-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-jarsigner-plugin/) which sounds like what you need.